# pTemplate not rendering in PrimeNG 16

Tags: html, angular, primeng, html-rendering, ng-template

I'm using primeng version 16 for a project, and have noticed that PrimeTemplates don't seem to render properly. The problem occurs even if editing [the demo code](https://primeng.org/menu#basic) on stackblitz, so I assume it's something to do with how I'm creating the template rather than anything about the way my project is set up.
A simple example:

```
<p-menu [model]="menuItems">
  <ng-template pTemplate="start">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </ng-template>
</p-menu>
```

The above code *should*, to my understanding, produce a menu with header text saying "Hello, world!" at the top. It does not. The menu renders as normal without the header template. This also occurs if the `ng-template` isn't nested within the `p-menu`.
I have imported the `SharedModule` that contains the `PrimeTemplate` class as well.
Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug?

Comment: Could you provide module and component class as well?